# An async interpreter for Lua to solve a multithreaded approach?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, asynchronous, lua

My general idea is that a single-threaded application ( the Lua interpreter ) will always deteriorate the performance of a multi-threaded application that depends on it ( a generic C++ application ).

To circumvent this problem I'm thinking about an asynchronous approach on the interpreter while keeping the C++ application multi-threaded, this basically means that based on my approach a Lua interpreter should somehow push the entire script/file in a scheduler with an asynchronous approach ( without waiting for the result ) and it's up to the well designed C++ multi-threaded messaging system to keep everything sequential.

The usual relationship is `C/C++ function <-> Lua` ( with a sequential approach ) ; I would like to have something like `C++ messaging system <-> entire Lua script` .

I'm also open to any kind of approach that can solve this and really help the mix between Lua and a C++ application designed for multi-threading.

Is this approach made possible by some piece of software ?

**EDIT**

I need something "user-proof" and I need to implement this behaviour right in C++/Lua API design.

Comment: Who is driving the choreography: C++ or LUA? If C++ calls into LUA can't you use many interpreter instances? If LUA calls into C++ you can spawn a thread for some methods and return immediately. If you don't need synchronization this can be reduced to a simple fire-and-forget from LUA.

Comment: @Pragmateek I'm supposed to offer Lua as a scripting solution for my C++ multithreaded application, so the critical part of the "flow" is from Lua to C++ . "Fire and forget" sounds a lot like how `std::async` works under C++11, ans it's interesting for me, can you expand a little bit more about how to do this in Lua and what are the mechanisms ?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to implement communication to lua as a co-routine. Messages are sent to C++ via coroutine.yield(messagedata), and then it sends back results via [lua_resume](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_resume). (See also: [lua_newthread](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_newthread)). You could even wrap your functions to provide a nicer event UI.

```
function doThing(thing, other, data)
  return coroutine.yield("doThing", thing, other, data)
end
```

You can still only have one thread running the lua interpreter at any given time (you will have to do locking) but you can have multiple such co-routines running concurrently.

Comment: nope, I need something "user-proof", meaning that I should implement this mechanism right in the API design. Thanks for that anyway, but I know that this will not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrency in Lua is a topic that has many many solutions. Here is a resource:

- http://lua-users.org/wiki/MultiTasking

You actually can make it easy for yourself since you do not actually have to run Lua itself multithreaded, which would impose a number of additional issues.

The obvious solution is running Lua in a separate thread but providing only a thin API for Lua in which every single API call immediately either forks a new thread/process or uses some sort of message passing for asynchronous data transfer, or even uses short-duration semaphores to read/write some values. This solution requires some sort of idle loop or event listeners unless you want to do busy waiting...

Another option that I think is still quite easy to implement with a new API, is actually the approach of [**node.js**](http://nodejs.org/):

- Run Lua in a separate thread
- Make your whole API of functions that only take callbacks. These callbacks are queued and can be scheduled by your C++ application.
- You can even, but do not have to, provide callback wrappers for the standard Lua API.

Example:

```
local version;
Application.requestVersionNumber(function(val) version = val; end)
```

Of course this example is riduculously trivial, but you get the idea.

One thing you should know though is that with the callback approach the scripts quickly get highly tiered if you are not careful. While that's not bad for performance, they can get hard to read.

Comment: infact I'm not interested in "multithreading" Lua, this will only create problem with the users and more room for errors. Can you provide some example/s with those C++ callbacks ?

Comment: @user2485710 The callbacks are Lua not C++. I'd rather not add an example of the C part, as there are a lot of things to consider, it's not just "give a short example", as one thing runs into the other or it would be so abstracted it probably wouldn't help you. Ask specific questions and I see if I can answer them.

Comment: ok, but I can influence the overall behaviour of the Lua interpreter ? I mean the solution that I have in mind right now is: make all the Lua functions async by default, Lua is just a scripting layer performing no computation and just firing functions without waiting for the result, so the Lua-user doesn't need to do anything and everything is transparent to him; after all the Lua-user wants ( in my case ) is a functional approach and he doesn't even care how it's implemented.

Comment: @user2485710 I'm not sure why you would want to change the behaviour of the interpreter (But you can, Lua is open source). How much Lua eventually does will depend on your application, API size and usefulness of your API functions to the user writing the Lua scripts, not on whether it is asynchronous or not.